# Getting rows from XML using XPath and Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'd like to get some rows (**z:row** rows) from XML using:

```
<rs:data>
    <z:row Attribute1="1" Attribute2="1" />
    <z:row Attribute1="2" Attribute2="2" />
    <z:row Attribute1="3" Attribute2="3" />
    <z:row Attribute1="4" Attribute2="4" />
    <z:row Attribute1="5" Attribute2="5" />
    <z:row Attribute1="6" Attribute2="6" />
</rs:data>
```

I'm having trouble using (**Python**):

```
ElementTree.parse('myxmlfile.xml').getroot().findall('//z:row')
```

I think that two points are invalid in that case.

Anyone knows how can I do that?

Comment: XPathGet is a function?  From what programming environment?

Comment: Consider XPathGet as a function that returns all nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I define the namespaces like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rs:data xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:rs="http://example.com/rs" xmlns:z="http://example.com/z">
  <z:row Attribute1="1" Attribute2="1" />
  <z:row Attribute1="2" Attribute2="2" />
  <z:row Attribute1="3" Attribute2="3" />
  <z:row Attribute1="4" Attribute2="4" />
  <z:row Attribute1="5" Attribute2="5" />
  <z:row Attribute1="6" Attribute2="6" />
</rs:data>
```

the Python [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)-API can be used like this:

```
ElementTree.parse("r.xml").getroot().findall('{http://example.com/z}row')
# => [<Element {http://example.com/z}row at 551ee0>, <Element {http://example.com/z}row at 551c60>, <Element {http://example.com/z}row at 551f08>, <Element {http://example.com/z}row at 551be8>, <Element {http://example.com/z}row at 551eb8>, <Element {http://example.com/z}row at 551f30>]
```

See also http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#xml-namespaces

Comment: The lxml tutorial may be more helpful: http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#namespaces

Comment: Just remember that "import lxml.etree" == "import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree" with a few exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to figure out setting up namespaces properly, you can ignore them like this:

```
XPathGet("//*[local-name() = 'row']")
```

Which selects every node whose name (without namespace) is `row`.

Answer (score 1):

The "z:" prefixes represent an XML namespace. you'll need to find out what that namespace is, and do the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"File.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("z", @"http://thenamespace.com");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(@"//z:row", ns);
```